# How to render a local XML with an XSL on a remote server

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt

At my application I am using XSLT to render XML files.

This is working fine when clients have xsl files:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="..\XSL\test.xsl"?>
```

But when I try to use an xsl file on my server in XML files like:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="http://www.mysite.com/xsl/test.xsl"?>
```

This is not working. 
It seems like a security restriction but is there a way to render local XML files with a remote XSL on a remote server?

Comment: What does "*when clients have xsl files*" mean? Are you opening your XML via `http://` or `file://`?

Answer (score 1):

The "security restriction" you're seeing is called [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). This means that your XSLT stylesheets must come from the same server your XML was loaded from.

If your XML comes from a server with scripting ability like PHP or so you can circumvent this by creating a proxy script. This script will essentially load the remote XSL file and make it appear to be a local one:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xsl');
echo file_get_contents('http://www.mysite.com/xsl/test.xsl');
?>
```

Comment: Clients get XML files from WCF application so they are opening them as a file from a folder. Because of that reason unfortunately they are not at the same origin.

Answer (score 1):

In IE11, there is still a workaround. You should go to "Internet options -> Security -> Local Internet -> Custom Level -> Miscellaneous -> Access data sources across domains" and set it to “Enable” or “Prompt”(last option is recommended in order you still have some control over this). This will enable loading/processing your local xml by remote xsl.

Comment: I don't think an IE11-specific solution is really helpful in this case; nor is a solution which requires all users to change security settings.